# Cannot align iframe element to center in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Friends! On my website, I need to put ads for which I have been provided with html code. I just need to put that into my website's html. Everything is working properly, but I am not able to align the ad to the middle of my page. I tried text-align:center, margin etc... but none of that worked. When I looked into the html in browser, I came to know that the html that is given  to be is rendered as an iframe. So how can I align it once it is rendered.

I also tried it using jquery:

```
 $('iframe').contents().find('html').find('body').find('div').css('text-align','center');
```

But this is also not working. Please find the html that is given to me on :
https://jsfiddle.net/1r1kydjz/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the iframe's body's first child a margin:auto and it will work:

```css
div[data-wrid^=WRID] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div data-wrid="WRID-145664652759935473" data-widgettype="staticBanner" data-responsive="yes" data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="90" width="728" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @symlink, It is working, but it was fine with width : 727px, with 469 it shifts towards right.

Comment: Hey!But it is not responsive, sorry I didn't mention it in my original question.

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. You should open a new question that describes this problem.